# OpenSSL: Verify certificate with CSCA file only works on PEM encoded files

Tags: certificate, openssl, trusted-root-certificates

I want to use the verify command on the commandline to verify a certificate using a CSCA file. This is my call with successful result:

```
openssl verify -verbose -CAfile CSCA_Certificate.pem cert.pem
cert.pem: OK
```

To make this work, I had to convert the files to PEM format. However, I want to use the DER encoded representations. This call fails:

```
openssl verify -verbose -CAfile CSCA_Certificate.der cert.der
```

The "-CAform" paramater is not recognized by openssl. I get the standard "usage" message. Does anyone have a hint on this? I'm quite new in openssl. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have been working with OpenSSL since January and I have noticed the same thing when signing certificate requests. It seems that OpenSSL is buggy if a DER certificate is used for certain operations. For that reason, I primarily use certificates encoded in PEM.

Comment: Can you edit your answer with a solution to help OP

Comment: @Sam I really don't have an answer. I don't think there is one; It is just a limitation of OpenSSL.